# I am trying to update data without page reload using live wire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Hi I am making a Private chat Application In Livewire but the Thing is When i Insert a message don't show Unless I reload the Page please help me how can i resolved that ? thank u.

I am using Livewire Full-Page Components here is the Code

Note :- I am using this render function inside viewMessage function but data is not updated without page relaod.

**this will load the all the conservation message**

$this->render();

**app\Http\Livewire\Messaging.php**

```
 class Messaging extends Component
    {
        public $body;
        public $searchTerm;
        public $selectedUser;
    
        public function mount(){
    
                $this->selectedUser =User::where('id','!=',Auth::user()->id)
                                    ->first();
    
        }
    
        public function render()
        {
                $searchTerm = '%'.$this->searchTerm.'%';
                if($searchTerm){
                  $user=  User::where('id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)
                    ->where('user_type',1)
                    ->where('email', 'like', $searchTerm)
                    ->with('messages')
                    ->get();
                }
    
                $conservation = Message::query()
                    ->where('sender_id',  Auth::user()->id)
                    ->where('receiver_id',  $this->selectedUser->id)
                    ->orWhere('receiver_id',  Auth::user()->id)
                    ->where('sender_id', $this->selectedUser->id)
                    ->with('sender')
                    ->with('receiver')
                    ->get();
    
              return view('livewire.messaging',[
    
                 'users'         => $user,
                 'conservation'  =>$conservation
            ]);
        }
    
        public function viewMessages($userId){
    
             $this->selectedUser = User::findorFail($userId);
    
                 $senderExist = Message::where('sender_id',$this->selectedUser->id)->exists();
    
                if($senderExist){
                    $message = Message::where('sender_id',$this->selectedUser->id)->orderBy('receiver_id','Desc')->get();
                        foreach($message as $value){
                            $value->notification = "0";
                            $value->save();
                        }
                }
    
        }
    
        public function sendMessages(){
    
    
            Message::create([
                'receiver_id'           =>      $this->selectedUser->id,
                'sender_id'             =>      Auth::user()->id,
                'body'                  =>      $this->body,
    
            ]);
    
            $this->reset('body');
            $this->viewMessages($this->selectedUser->id);
            $this->render(); //this will load the all the conservation message
        }
    }
```

**resources\views\livewire\messaging.blade.php**

```
         <form wire:submit.prevent="sendMessages" action="#" >
                <div class="position-absolute bottom-0 col-md-12 pe-3">
                    <div class="input-group comment-box p-3">
                    <input wire:model.defer="body"    type="text" class="form-control" 
               placeholder="Type Message ..." aria-label="Aa" aria-describedby="button-addon2" required>
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary py-0 px-3" type="submit" id="button-addon2"><i class='bx bx-send fs-4'></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would not suggest loading in data on every single render. Livewire is able to hydrate previously fetched models and collections, which takes away the strain of reloading it from your database each render. I personally would write your component as such:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class Messaging extends Component
{
    public $body = '';
    public $searchTerm = '';
    public $selectedUser;

    // Assuming you're using PHP 7.4 or above, else remove typehint
    public Collection $users; 
    public Collection $conversation;
  
    // Ensure we validate the data passed
    protected $rules = [
        'body' => ['required', 'string'],
    ];
  
    public function mount()
    {
        $this->selectedUser = User::where('id','!=',Auth::user()->id)->first();
      
        $this->getUsers();
        $this->getConversation();
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.messaging');
    }
  
    public function updated($field)
    {
        // Only update the users if the search term has changed
        if ($field === 'searchTerm') {
            $this->getUsers():
        }
    }

    public function viewMessages($userId)
    {
        $this->selectedUser = User::findorFail($userId);

        $senderExist = Message::where('sender_id',$this->selectedUser->id)->exists();

        if($senderExist) {
            $messages = Message::where('sender_id',$this->selectedUser->id)->orderBy('receiver_id','desc')->get();
            
            foreach($messages as $message){
                $message->notification = "0";
                $message->save();
            }
          
            // Are you saving the messages one by one to trigger model events? If not, use below query to instantly update all of them at once in the database:
          
//            Message::where('sender_id',$this->selectedUser->id)->orderBy('receiver_id','desc')->update([
//              'notification' => 0,
//            ]);
        }
    }

    public function sendMessages()
    {
        // Validate the data as per given rules
        $this->validate();

        Message::create([
            'receiver_id' => $this->selectedUser->id,
            'sender_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'body' => $this->body,
        ]);

        $this->reset('body');
        $this->viewMessages($this->selectedUser->id);
        // Refresh conversation
        $this->getConversation();
    }
  
    public function getConversation()
    {
        $this->converstaion = Message::query()
          ->where('sender_id',  Auth::user()->id)
          ->where('receiver_id',  $this->selectedUser->id)
          ->orWhere('receiver_id',  Auth::user()->id)
          ->where('sender_id', $this->selectedUser->id)
          ->with('sender')
          ->with('receiver')
          ->get();
    }
  
    public function getUsers()
    {
        $query = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)
          ->where('user_type', 1)
          ->with('messages');
      
      
        if (! empty($this->searchTerm)) {
            $searchTerm = '%'.$this->searchTerm.'%';
            $query->where('email', 'like', $searchTerm);
        }
      
        $this->users = $query->get();
    }
}
```

The render method gets called by Livewire itself each time *something* happens, such as a value change of a variable, or after a function was called. You should not call it yourself.

P.S. For Livewire to fully keep track of what is what, I suggest adding `wire:key` to data rows. For example, on a `div` that is holding the data to your conversation messages, add `wire:key="message-{{$message->id}}"`. This way, if a data change happens, Livewire knows exactly what date should be changed. Read more about it [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting#dom-diffing-issues)

Comment: Actully few days ago my code was working perfectly with $this->render() but now it's not working . why is it not working now ?

Comment: Well then you must have made a change. Still, it's not suggested to call `$this->render()`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the livewire emite event
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events